# Office network instant messenger recommendation?

Tags: windows, collaboration, chat

We're looking at expanding our office, which will mean that we'll have to separate offices. This will make communication a bit more difficult, because any time we have a question, we'll need to rely on email, which can have a bit of a delay.

So instead the idea of the use of a network instant messenger comes to mind.

We'll be using a VPN, for communication between the Domain Controllers on each site, with a LAN network in each location.

OS: Windows 7 Pro/10 Pro (Currently using 7 Pro, but we are upgrading to 10 Pro shortly)

Possible features:

- If needed, we want to be able to save conversations
- We want to restrict who we add to the contact list, perhaps restrict it to admin rights only
- Can add files (not essential, we can use email to send attachments)
- Group chat feature would be useful, but not necessary
- Preferably free or low cost
- Preferably not cloud based

Comment: For which operating system(s) should the client be available? And I guess you want to self-host the server (if the chat protocol needs one), correct? Support of group chats? With "save conversations", do you mean storing the chat log (if yes, on the clients and/or on the server)?

Comment: @unor I have added some of the information to the question, but to clarify: self-host server - preferably yes (just keeps it neat) but not essential; Group chats - preferable, but not essential; save the chat log - yes, but the location isn't a necessity, that can be managed separately if needed.

Comment: Are cloud-based solutions OK? Do you need voice?

Comment: Is your question the same as http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18754/alternatives-to-slack-for-team-communication ? If not, please detail why each solution proposed there does not fit your needs. Thanks! :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul preferably not cloud based, as we don't have anything set up for that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Now please detail why http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/22964/140 does not fit your needs.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Sorry! I didn't mean that didn't fit, I haven't had a proper look at it yet! Haha!

Comment: OK, please let us know as soon as you can :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30470/discussion-between-ben-and-nicolas-raoul).